# Unrolling recursive recurrence relations

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, relation, recurrence

I couldn't find a solution to my question since usually the solution (in big Os terms) is what's asked, but not the unrolled recurrence.
If that was asked already just tell me and I'll delete.

I had this question in my Algorithms and Data Structures test in uni, and I've been banging my head on this one for a while. Mostly because I don't get how I'd come to the right answer.

I have the following relation:

```
T(1)=2
T(n)=2T(n-1)+2 for n>=2
```

The answers are:

```
1. T(n)= 2^n+1 -2
2. T(n)= none of the answers are correct 
3. T(n)= 1/2n(n+1)-1 
4. T(n)= 2^n+1 -2-n
5. T(n)= n+ (-1)^n
```

This is what I tried:

```
T(1)=2
T(n)=2T(n-1)+2 -> T(n-1) = T(n-2)+2 
    =2T(n-2)+2+2 
    =2T(n-2)+4 -> T(n-2) = T(n-3)+3 
    =2T(n-3)+2+4 
    =2T(n-3)+6 so then -> 2T(n-k)+2k and if n=k 2T(n-n)+2n -> 2T(0)+2n
```

BUT I don't have the T(0) case.
Also, this method would ultimately bring me to know the big O solution, although it's not what I'm trying to find now.

Would anyone be kind enough to explain me the right method to get to the right answer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't *unroll* the answers, just check them.

So for each of the possible answers check if `T(1)=2`, and if substituting the given `T(n)` gives equality for `T(n)=2T(n-1)+2`. So for the first answer `T(1)=2^(n+1)-2=4-2=2` (as it should be) and:

```
T(n) =?= 2*T(n)+2
2^(n+1)-2 =?= 2*(2^(n)-2)+2
```

Using the simply =?= to mean the equality to check.
Simplify both sides leads to:

```
2^(n+1)-2 =?= 2*2^(n)-2
```

The rest I leave to you

Comment: In T(n)=2^(n+1)+2 if i substitute T(1)=2 I get 2^3 -2 = 6
In T(n)=2T(n-1)+2 if i substitute T(1)=2 I get 2*2(2-1)+2= 6
So I get equality between the two, which would tell me the answer is correct. Is this what you mean?

Edit: 
Also, checking with the other answers, they would give me 3, 2 and 4 as results, which aren't 6.

Comment: No, for that one -  keep the n in the formula and check if 2^(n+1)-2 and 2*2^n-2 are the same (for all values of n). However, clearly the others are wrong since you found a value where the formula was wrong.

Comment: Would it make sense to use the method I used to see if the values in the formulas are wrong? Because it worked this time, but idk if it would work again. 
Most importantly, checking if 2^(n+1)-2 and 2*2^n-2 are the same for all values of n works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

T(n)=2T(n-1)+2 is equivalent to T(n)+2 = 2(T(n-1)+2).

So T(n)+2 = 2^(n-1)(T(1)+2) = 2^(n-1)*4 = 2^(n+1). Thus T(n) = 2^(n+1)-2.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is **similar** to https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18900/how-do-i-show-tn-2tn-1-k-is-o2n

You might understand how to solve this too...

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to notice that it's exponential, and then just check the two exponential answers...

But if you want to unroll it, then you get:

```
T(n) = 2 + 2T(n-1)
     = 2 + 4 + 4T(n-2)
     = 2 + 4 + 8 + 8T(n-3)
     = 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2^(n-1)T(1)
     = 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2^n
```

and then you recognize the progression and do:

```
T(n) = 2T(n) - T(n)
     = 2^(n+1) - 2
```

Answer (score 0):

For the progression, it helps to think of the chain like :

```
126 

=  111 111 0 (base-2)
```

---

```
=  2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * (+ 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 0

=  2 * (2 * (2 * \
  (2 * (2 * (2 * ( + 1) + 1) + 1) \
                   + 1) + 1) + 1) + 0
```